# Chrome browser not passing authorization headers after restarting the browser

Tags: c#, google-chrome, authentication

I have a web application - using Windows Authentication, which makes ajax requests. The browser asks the credentials and everything works fine. Once I restart the browser, and I try to fetch the data - I am receiving 401 Unauthorized error and browser do not ask any credentials.

When I go to Chrome Console and I open the failed WebAPI request in a separate tab- the browser then asks the credentials - after which the app also works fine.

How can I force the browser to ask the credentials without opening the WebApi request in a separate tab?

I have tried changing Authentication Providers in IIS to Negotiate, NTLM.
I have added with credentials while making AJAX requests

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
            timeout: 30000,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            crossDomain: true
        });
```

The browser is expected to ask credentials after 401 unauthorized requests.